# Magento - Are these files safe to include on .gitignore file?

Tags: git, magento, magento-1.7, gitignore

I have a `Magento 1.7` website.

Then I have auto generated files in the form:

```
...
media/captcha/base/ff3f35b1bbc191988318a9893282f063.png
var/cache/mage--0/mage---331_Zend_LocaleC_en_US_currencynumber_
var/session/sess_58ap4vgtog56j8ojruiurgecp0
var/report/1058813543850
...
```

like on the image below:

[image]

New files like these are auto generated all the time.

I have this website on a `Git` repository.

Then I want to know if in case I remove all these files that could cause the website stop working as expected. I mean, some content doesn't show up, etc.

If the `media/captcha/base/*` files are used just once for captcha validation then for sure I could remove those files without any problem.

If the `var/cache/mage--0/*` files are used as support to display some content but if they are missing and then needed they are re-auto-generated, then for sure I could remove those files without any problem.

My goal here is to know if I could add these files to the `.gitignore` file so I don't get new changes to commit to the website repository when it is not really necessary.

For example, in the case of images uploaded via some `WYSIWYG` editor, I could not add those images to the `.gitingore` file because if I remove those files from the repository, then on the website will be missing content on the corresponding page when installing the website on another server (downloading the `Git` repository to it).

**This is my question**

> What are the Magento file patterns I should add to the `.gitignore` file in order to have consistency when moving a website from one server to another by downloading a `Git` repository?

Know this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those files are all generate in, for instance,  media/captcha/base/*, all you need to do is:

- make sure those files are not tracked (but are still present in your local drive)

  ```
  git rm -R --cached media/captcha/base/
  ```
- add the all folder to the .gitignore file

  ```
  echo /media/captcha/base/>.gitignore
  git add .gitignore
  git commit -m "ignore media/captcha/base/ folder"
  ```

As for the *magento* files to ignore, see [`github/gitignore/Magento.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Magento.gitignore) (or [`gitignore.io/api/magento`](https://www.gitignore.io/api/magento), or [`gitignore.io/api/magento2`](https://www.gitignore.io/api/magento2))

It would involve:

```
#--------------------------#
# Magento Default Files    #
#--------------------------#

/app/etc/local.xml

/media/*
!/media/.htaccess

!/media/customer
/media/customer/*
!/media/customer/.htaccess

!/media/dhl
/media/dhl/*
!/media/dhl/logo.jpg

!/media/downloadable
/media/downloadable/*
!/media/downloadable/.htaccess

!/media/xmlconnect
/media/xmlconnect/*

!/media/xmlconnect/custom
/media/xmlconnect/custom/*
!/media/xmlconnect/custom/ok.gif

!/media/xmlconnect/original
/media/xmlconnect/original/*
!/media/xmlconnect/original/ok.gif

!/media/xmlconnect/system
/media/xmlconnect/system/*
!/media/xmlconnect/system/ok.gif

/var/*
!/var/.htaccess

!/var/package
/var/package/*
!/var/package/*.xml
```

Comment: I know the actions I should take after I get the answer to my question: what are the file patterns I need to add to `.gitignore`?. I edited my post highlighting my question.

Comment: The point of my answer is to ignore the all folder content, not a pattern

Comment: yes, sure. But, could you specify on your answer (edit) what are the Magento directories I should ignore other than `media/captcha/base/`, plus maybe others I listed at the begining of my question, like: `var/cache/`, `var/session/`, `var/report/`, plus maybe others you consider?. I'm not sure if add or not the previous directories I listed right here. This is a `Magento` question, not a `Git` question.

Comment: @Angel Right. I have added a typical magento `.gitignore` file.